# Add auto increment back to primary key column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, auto-increment, rails-migrations

By mistake I removed the autoincrement option from id field of my table. Can anyone tell me how I can reinsert the option of autoincrement back through migration?

Answer (score 21):

Try:

```
change_column :my_table, :id, :primary_key
```

or

```
my_table.change_column :id, :primary_key
```

Certain Rails database adapters may not let you call `change_column` on the primary key.  If that is the case then you can always call `execute` to perform the change using SQL directly:

MySQL:

```
execute('ALTER TABLE "my_table" CHANGE "id" "id"
  bigint DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY')
```

PostgreSQL (method 1):

```
max_id = execute(%%Q{SELECT id FROM "my_table" ORDER BY "id" DESC
  LIMIT 1}).to_a.first
execute(%%Q{CREATE SEQUENCE "my_table_id_seq" START #{max_id+1}})
execute(%%Q{ALTER TABLE "my_table" ALTER COLUMN "id"
  TYPE bigint})
execute(%%Q{ALTER TABLE "my_table" ALTER COLUMN "id"
  SET DEFAULT nextval('my_table_id_seq'::regclass)})
execute(%%Q{ALTER TABLE "my_table" ADD PRIMARY KEY("id")})
```

PostgreSQL (method 2):

```
max_id = execute(%%Q{SELECT "id" FROM "my_table" ORDER BY "id" DESC
  LIMIT 1}).to_a.first
execute(%%Q{ALTER TABLE "my_table" RENAME COLUMN "id" TO "id_orig"})
execute(%%Q{ALTER TABLE "my_table" ADD COLUMN "id" bigserial NOT NULL})
execute(%%Q{UPDATE "my_table" SET "id"="id_orig"})
execute(%%Q{ALTER SEQUENCE "my_table_id_seq" RESTART #{max_id+1}})
execute(%%Q{ALTER TABLE "my_table" DROP COLUMN "id_orig"})
```

If you do not want to use `bigint`/`bigserial` (64-bit), use `int(11)`/`integer`/`serial` instead.

Comment: Thnx for yor response,But i have actually already done change_column on some of the primary keys.May be thats why it removed the already existing Auto Increment option from the primary key option.

Answer (score 8):

I didn't check other versions but on Rails 5 you can just set the `auto_increment` option:

```
change_column :table_name, :id, :int, null: false, unique: true, auto_increment: true
```

Or if you want a bigint:

```
change_column :table_name, :id, :bigint, null: false, unique: true, auto_increment: true
```

Comment: need more option, that is `primary_key: true`

Answer (score 1):

Your Postgres code does not work, it's impossible to use serial or bigserial in an ALTER TABLE statement. Correct SQL for PostgreSQL is

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN id TYPE int 
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN id TYPE bigint
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, created a primary column and gave ids to all the rows.

```
add_column :tags_posts_rel, :id, :primary_key
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who came here (like I did) in an effort to figure out how to make a custom `id` column that uses `bigint` instead of `int`, what I didn't realize is that for Rails 5.1 and above, `bigint` is the default type for id

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26266

Answer (score 0):

***Change Column***

Rails5

```
change_column :table_name, :id, :int, null: false, unique: true, auto_increment: true,  primary_key: true
```

Rails6

```
change_column :table_name, :id, :int, null: false, unique: true, auto_increment: true,  primary_key: true
```

***Add Column***
Rails5

```
add_column :table_name, :id, :int, null: false, unique: true, auto_increment: true,  primary_key: true
```

Rails6

```
add_column :table_name, :id, :int, null: false, unique: true, auto_increment: true,  primary_key: true
```